# "Every garment" or "every piece of garment"

Tags: uncountable-nouns, countable-nouns

The dictionary definition of *garment* is

> an item of clothing

Should I write *every garment* or *every piece of garment*?  The second one sounds more correct to me, but it's wordier.  Is the first one grammatically correct also?

An example sentence:

> In the suitcase, every garment seems brand-new.

Essentially, is `garment` countable or not countable?

If it is countable, you can say:

```
three garments
```

if not, you have to say:

```
three pieces of garment
```

or

```
three articles of garment
```

(if `piece` or `article` isn't correct, what noun should I use instead?)

Comment: To me *a piece of garment* would imply just a sleeve of a shirt, or one leg of a pair of trousers.

Answer (score 1):

***[Garment](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/garment)*** is a countable noun:

> - a piece of clothing.

I'd avoid using "a piece of garment" to indicate an article of clothing.

***[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=piece%20of%20garment%2C%20piece%20of%20clothing&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpiece%20of%20garment%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpiece%20of%20clothing%3B%2Cc0)***  ***piece of garment*** vs ***piece of clothing***.

Comment: If `garment` is `a piece of clothing`, then `garment` and `clothing` are equivalent, or nearly equivalent?  Why do you suggest to "avoid" this usage?  Thank you

Comment: No a garment is a shirt, a blouse, a pair of trousers etc. You use ***piece of*** with ***clothing*** because it is a non countable noun, like luggage. A piece of garment is a part of a shirt, trousers  etc.

Answer (score 1):

"Piece of garment" is valid syntax but means (as a comment indicates) a sleeve or leg or some other fragment of a garment.

"Garment" by itself can certainly be used, in singular or plural -- it is a fairly normal countable noun.

"Clothing" is not a countable noun, and so with that word you'd use "piece of clothing".